# Error on sudo apt-get update

Tags: raspbian, wifi, wireless, apt, wireless-adapter

I'm getting the below error when updating raspian.
I connect via SSH via putty on the fixed wlan0 ip.

Now when i run `sudo apt-get update` i get errors like below.

Err http://raspberrypi.collabora.com wheezy Release.gpg
  **Something wicked happened resolving 'raspberrypi.collabora.com:http' (-5 - No address associated with hostname)**

I have been playing around with interfaces so i can fix (static my ip's)
It may be related to that what is happening so im pasting my interfaces file below so you have a look. Thanks

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback


##--eth0 static ip configuration--##
#auto eth0
#allow-hotplug eth0
#iface eth0 inet static
#               address 192.168.1.51
#               netmask 255.255.255.0
#               network 192.168.1.0
#               broadcast 192.168.1.255
#               gateway 192.168.1.1


##--eth0 dinamic ip configuration--##

allow-hotplug eth0
iface eth0 inet dhcp


##-- wlan0 static ip configuration-- ##
allow-hotplug wlan0
auto wlan0
iface wlan0 inet static
        address 192.168.1.50
        netmask 255.255.255.0
        network 192.168.0.0
        gateway 192.168.1.1
        wpa-ssid "my ssid"
        wpa-psk "my password"
```

Comment: Looks like something is wrong with dns mechanism. 1. Try pinging google. If it's not working, it's surely a "resolv" problem. 2. Change static to dhcp momentarily, reboot to make it effective and see if it works.

Comment: I connect only via ssh , will i be able to connect after setting wlan0 to dhcp ?

Comment: @JorgeVidinha sure you can connect via SSH when using DHCP, but the trick is to find the IP address to use because it might change after each OS start-up. I say might because you can reserve some fix IP address based on MAC address on a DHCP server, so it is still possible to have the same IP address when using DHCP.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't have to change to dhcp.

`cat /etc/resolve.conf` should show you which dns servers are currently configured.

As dastaan said, you can just type `ping google.com` to see if you are resolving basic addresses. You can also use `nslookup google.com`

To add a dns server w/o changing your permanent setup, just add the entries to /etc/resolv.conf. This should reset when you reboot. The below will use the google dns servers.

```
nameserver 8.8.8.8
nameserver 8.8.4.4
```

Adding it permanently is a different animal. I would edit /etc/network/interfaces and under the wlan0 block add the following line:

```
dns-nameservers 8.8.8.8 8.8.4.4
```

Comment: Added the resolve.conf file with google dns that was missing , added the last line under wlan0, in meantime deactivated eth0 and its now working with wlan0. And learned that although eth0 is commented on both static and dinamic modes on /network/interfaces file every time i connect the LAN cable it receives a dynamic IP anyway. Is this expected ? This is probably another question

Comment: @JorgeVidinha you should not edit /etc/resolv.conf as your changes will be lost (on Debian-based systems). Adding the `dns-nameservers` line ought to be enough. Note: that using Google's DNS might have privacy issue. So choosing carefully your DNS server is important to protect yourself.

Comment: I did it still getting error: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45531150/unable-to-ping-google-com-from-raspberry-pi-2

Answer (score 3):

Usually via DHCP you get also the names of the DNS servers to use so that you Debian/Raspbian can automatically configure them in order to resolve hostnames into IP addresses (and vice versa).

When you go *static* you need to specify it. On recent Debian/Ubuntu, this is done like follow, and I believe that this would be similar on Raspbian.

Add an extra line to your interfaces configuration for your wlan0:

```
dns-nameservers <dns names separated by spaces>
```

(e.g. `dns-nameservers 12.34.56.78 12.34.56.79` but use your DNS server(s)).