# Cannot connect Pi 3 to internet

Tags: raspbian, networking, pi-3

My son and I are complete newbies when it comes to pi and Raspbian. We've just bought a pi 3 and have set up Raspbian from Noobs. We can connect to our router using both WiFi and Ethernet but cannot connect to any sites using the browser. The router is working normally with other devices. I'm inclined to think the pi is faulty, but looking for suggestions to try before I send it back.

Comment: If you can connect to the router via Ethernet and WiFI it is highly unlikely that the Pi is defective. How did you configure the network? What is the output of ping 8.8.8.8? what is the output of ping google.com? How do you know you can connect to the router? Please edit your question and add the above details - do not add them to the comments.

Comment: http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/q/12919/24224

Comment: I had try to reinstall follow this tutorial: [Setup Raspberry Pi Without a Monitor, Keyboard or HDMI Cable](https://youtu.be/eoAzkfi6FXQ) After reinstall and repair ethernet cable. My raspberry can access internet. Please check ethernet cable. My problem come from my cable.