# What will I need to make display work with Pi Zero?

Tags: hdmi, display, pi-zero

At first, sorry for this noob question, I am total newbie in Raspberry and I want to hear from experienced people. I ordered Pi Zero *without any accessories* and I want to know if I will need some additional hardware to make this display work with it: 
[eBay link](http://www.ebay.co.uk/itm/New-3-5-TFT-LCD-Touch-Screen-Module-320-480-RGB-Display-Board-For-Raspberry-Pi-/281630179282)
Will I need to do some soldering or just connect it with cable?
And one more question - [can I enable virtual keyboard](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/41150/virtual-keyboard-activation) on  3.5" display?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You step going to need to purchase a GPIO header accessory. Adafruit Industries sell [this](https://www.adafruit.com/products/2822)

, but you will need to solder it to the board they say. As the for Virtual keyboard, I have only seen two options for the Pi and they most likely won't work with the 3.5" screen.

Comment: @PKM No problem. Also, a small lightweight wireless keyboard meant for the Pi is [this](http://www.memoryexpress.com/Products/MX58195)

Comment: That's quite pricey, I do not want to make bigger investments, because this will be my first time working with microcomputers, and I don't know if I find it interesting //EDIT: Don't you know what is minimal size for virtual keyboard?

Comment: @PKM You can try either one of these keyboards: `sudo apt-get install florence` or `sudo apt-get install matchbox-keyboard`

Comment: You can now buy a Pi Zero (W) with GPIO header already soldered on. I got a cheap Ali Express 3.5" screen to work