# Is there any way to enter Wifi PW via my mouse (no keyboard)

Tags: wifi, keyboard, mouse, accessibility

Just got my first Raspberry and don't have a spare keyboard around. I was hoping there would be a key pallet utility to use for my password but can't find one. Help!

Comment: You can SSH from another computer and use the command line to configure your WiFi. You can also temporarily use a keyboard to make the settings then return it to the other computer.

Answer (score 1):

There isn't an onscreen keyboard installed by default on Raspbian, so your choices are (in ascending order of hassle):

**Borrow a keyboard from another computer**

**SSH or console cable into the Pi and change the password on the console** (needs a bit of Googling if you don't know how)

**SSH or console cable into the Pi and [install the onscreen keyboard](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/41150/virtual-keyboard-activation), then put it in on the graphical mode**