# How to install on screen keyboard in raspbian without a physical keyboard?

Tags: raspbian, pi-3, raspbian-jessie, keyboard

I dont have a physical k/b with me, but I have a mouse. For installing matchbox-keyboard, I dont have a physical keyboard. Although ssh is enabled in the system, when I try to connect, it says no route to host. Without a keyboard, I cant restart the service too. So is there a way to install matchbox-keyboard offline, using a .deb file or something?

Update : I downloaded .deb file and try to install, but it requires me to enter password, which I cannot.

Comment: I have the little Rpi with the 3.5 inch LCD screen.  This would be handy.  But instead, I use XRDP and set up scripts that I can run by clicking on them with the stylus.  No matter how you slice it, you will want a physical keyboard (and mouse is handy) to set up whatever solution you decide to use.

Comment: You can check this link https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/41150/virtual-keyboard-activation?newreg=514c528b9ecf434ba86e1f73bf614bdb

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I got it done by enabling vnc server in the pi, then connect to it using a client in my laptop. After that, I installed the keyboard in the pi.

Answer (score 7):

If you want to do this but can't connect your Pi to the internet via cable do this:

1. Open LibreOffice Writer
2. Insert - Special characters...
3. With mouse you can type your WiFi password
4. Turn on WiFi, connect to your network by copying password from
   LibreOffice
5. Proceed with the installing matchbox-keyboard or setting up VNC

Answer (score 5):

Another option I just used is to put the commands and password for WiFi in a text document on a USB drive. You can open the file and copy and paste as needed.

Answer (score 2):

I tried to do it via connecting to hotspot with no password but comes out that SSH is not enabled (I guess the issue is with firewall or sth).

How I solved it was using the graphical package manager (Raspberry logo on upper left -> Preferences -> Add/Remove software) to install virtual keyboard and typing my wifi password. After that, the SSH worked flawlessly.

1. Open **Add/Remove Software**
2. Installing software is going to ask for password, so find it for example under System section, under 'R' is raspberrypi kernel headers, where you can copy word `raspberry` if you have default password
3. Find `matchbox-keyboard` under the System section and install it clicking by 'Apply'
4. Done! Open virtual keyboard from Accessories and you can type in your secured Wifi password, after which ssh should work fine. If not, then you can still use terminal, to restart the daemon or whatever needs to be done.

Answer (score 1):

You have two methods. First method: via SSH. To enable SSH you must:

1. Raspbian -> Preferences -> Raspberry Pi Configuration
2. Clicks on "Interfaces" tab
3. Enable "SSH" and clicks "OK"
4. Connect RPi via wire to your router (or computer, but you must have configured DHCP server)
5. Go mouse on network panel item, you will se your IP on tooltip pop-up box
6. Now you can connect to RPi via SSH (user: pi, password: raspberry) and [install screen keyboard](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/41150/virtual-keyboard-activation).

Second method, via VNC:

1. Raspbian -> Preferences -> Raspberry Pi Configuration
2. Clicks on "Interfaces" tab
3. Enable "VNC" and clicks "OK". But it is not all because you get ["No configured security type"](https://support.jumpdesktop.com/hc/en-us/articles/216424363-VNC-VNC-Server-Error-No-configured-security-type-is-supported-by-3-3-viewer) error.
4. Right click on VNC Server panel item and click "Options..." in popup menu.
5. In "Security" tab change authentication to "VNC password" and type password (can not be blank), you can open Chromium Browser, select some word, copy via mouse right click and clicks copy and paste in VNC password dialog box :)
6. Clicks "Apply"
7. Now you can connect via vncviewer from linux console.