# virtual keyboard RPI 3 model B

Tags: pi-3

I tried installing the virtual key board as described here:

[Virtual keyboard activation](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/41150/virtual-keyboard-activation)

on my RPI 3  model B Board

but it doesn't work at all

I get this when installing:

```
pi@raspberrypi:/ $ sudo apt-get install matchbox-keyboard
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree        
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
matchbox-keyboard : Depends: libfakekey0 (>= 0.1) but it is not going to be installed
                 Recommends: matchbox-keyboard-im but it is not going to be installed
 python2.7 : Depends: python2.7-minimal (= 2.7.9-2+deb8u2) but 2.7.9-2+deb8u1 is to be installed
         Depends: libpython2.7-stdlib (= 2.7.9-2+deb8u2) but 2.7.9-2+deb8u1 is to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

I tried this:

```
pi@raspberrypi:/ $ apt-get -f install

E: Could not open lock file /var/lib/dpkg/lock - open (13: Permission denied)
E: Unable to lock the administration directory (/var/lib/dpkg/), are you root?
pi@raspberrypi:/ $
```

Comment: You forgot `sudo`.

Answer (score 2):

Please look at the very last question: **are you root?**. That is what you get by prefixing your commands with `sudo`. So try your command with:

```
rpi ~$ sudo apt-get -f install
```

Comment: GREAT   - it helped. I have a  Keyboard  now

Comment: @eranreshef Glad to help you :-) It would be nice if you could accept the answer with a tick on the tick on the left side. It will finish the question and show others that it has a solution.