# Unable to ping Google.com from raspberry pi 2 , also error during sudo apt-get update

Tags: pi-2

I have Pi 2 installed with raspberries OS

All the setting as default and its connected to WiFI, signal strength looks good. Here its :

[image]

However, I'm unable to ping Google. I have referred this ( [Error on sudo apt-get update](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/32849/error-on-sudo-apt-get-update) )

Still no help. Is there any minimum WIFI speed requirement there for PI 2 ? Also, is there any minimum Power supply requirement?

During update: I'm getting the messages as below and looks like it stopped :

err http://mirrordirector.respbian.org wheezy/non-free raanslation-en_GB something wicked happened resolving mirrordirector.respbian.org (-5 - no address associated with hostname)

6% [Connecting to mirroedirector.raspbian.org]

E: Some index files failed to download.They have been ignored or old ones used instead.

How can i access the website from its browser, also how to make an update and upgrade success? How to know if the board is really connected to internet or now?

Not only Google, Looks like unable to access any website- why? am I missing some configuration?

here is how sudoedit /etc/network/interfaces looks like:

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

auto eth0
allow-hotplug ath0
iface eth0 inet manual

auto wlan0
allow-hotplug wlan0
iface wlan0 inet manual
wpa-conf /etc/wpa_supplicane/wpa_supplicant.conf
dns-nameservers 8.8.4.4 8.8.8.8

auto wlan1
```

allow-hotplug wlan1
   iface wlan1 inet manual
   wpa-conf /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf

MY lsmod gives this result:

```
cfg80211 386508 2 mac80211,rt2x00lib
```

the lsusb gives:

```
bus 001 device 004 : id 148f:5370 Ralink Technology,Corp RT5370 wireless 
adapter
```

the uname -r gives :

```
3.18.11-v7+
```

Note: I'm able to ping my SSID's IP address from the Board. However, I'm unable to ping my laptop from the board, even though it's on the same network.

Whats going wrong? Please help.

Comment: Do you fixed the typo in `/etc/network/interfaces`? Does it work now?

Answer (score 1):

I noticed that in your `/etc/network/interfaces` file you have the line;

```
wpa-conf /etc/wpa_supplicane/wpa_supplicant.conf
```

There is a miss-spelling of supplicant in there. It should read

```
wpa-conf /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf
```